# Volume of a rotated region $y = x^2 + 2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have no idea what the best method to do this is but I chose the shell method.

$y = x^2 + 2$

about $y = -2$

So I convert to f(y) since it rotates on a horizontal axis.

$x = \sqrt{y-2}$

I know the bound are 0 to 4 for either x or y, it doesn't really matter.

I know that the -2 term is lower than the lowest bound so that I will substract that term.

$$2\pi \int y(\sqrt{y-4} + 2)dy$$

From here I am stuck, I do not know how to integrate that. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: The region that is being rotated is not specified. The integral is not quite right in any case. But one cannot answer the question fully without a full description of the region.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but you need to specify your limits of integration that are defined by some restriction on $x$ axis, since the body formed by that rotation is open.

Comment: I said 0 to 4 in the post.

Comment: The bounds cannot be $0$ to $4$ for $y$, since $y$ is always $\ge 2$. The region we are rotating should first be clearly described.

Comment: Are you sure your function is $y=x^2+2$? Because this would become $x=\sqrt{y-2}$ if you solve for $x$. Furthermore, as AndreNicolas pointed out, this function is only defined for $y\geq 2$, since $x^2$ is nonnegative. Hence it is impossible to rotate around $y=-2$, so also be sure to check if this is the correct line you want to rotate about.

Comment: This is what the book has.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: The book undoubtedly describes a *region* that has to be rotated, not a curve that has to be rotated. One description might be "The region below the curve $y=2+x^2$, above the $x$-axis, from $x=$ to $x=$." Another description (of a different region) might go 'the region below $y=4$ and above the curve $y=x^2+2$." You need to describe the region. Then one can find the volume. And by the way shells is not easiest here.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes it is the region below the curve to y = 0

Comment: @PaulthePirate: You have written that it is the region below the curve and above (or equivalently on or above) the line $y=0$. From $x=$ where to $x=$ where? Presumably $x=0$ to $x=4$. I will write up a solution, since the currentky posted answer is not quite right. Please edit your post since the question does not make sense at this time.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't make sense, what do I need to clarify?

Comment: Does "I know the bounds are $0$ to $4$ for either $x$ or $y$, it doesn't really matter" make sense? Does it make sense to ask for the volume when a region is rotated about the line $y=-2$ if the region being rotated is not specified? In these problems, the geometry is often of great importance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x) = y = x^2 + 2$.

**If you are given the bounds** for $x$ between $0$ and $4$, those bounds are not the same bounds as $y$, since we are not given $y = x$. Rather, the bounds for $y$ are $f(0)= y = 2$ to $f(4) = y =18$. I will proceed using those bounds for $y$.

Note also that $y = x^2 + 2$ corresponds to $x = \sqrt{y - 2}$.

So our desired integral is $$2\pi \int_2^{18} (y+2)\sqrt{y - 2} \,dy$$

You can use substitution: Let $$u = y - 2 \iff y = u+2 \implies dy = du$$

$$y+2 = (u+2)+2 = u+4$$

And our new bounds are then $u \in [0, 16]$, since, when $y = 2,\;u = 2 - 2 = 0$, and when $y = 18, \; u= 18-2 = 16$.

Substituting gives us $$\begin{align} 2\pi\int_0^{16} (u+4)u^{1/2} \,du \quad & = \quad 2\pi\int_0^{16} \left(u^{3/2} +  4u^{1/2}\right) \,du \\ \\  & = \quad 2\pi\left(\frac{2u^{5/2}}{5} + \frac{8u^{3/2}}{3}\right)\Big|_{u = 0}^{u =16}\end{align}$$

Comment: You were close in your set-up, PaulthePirate: Here though, we subtract $y = -2$ from $y$ to get $(y - (-2)) = y+2$, and multiply by the "height" which is given by $\sqrt{y -2}$. Then, recall that in the substitution integral, we have that $(u + 4)\sqrt u = (u + 4)u^{1/2} = (u^{2/2} + 4)u^{1/2}= u^{3/2} + 4u^{1/2}$. Then integrating is just applying the power rule.

Comment: Here too, Paul, no follow up questions: Put a lot of time into this post as well. I guess that time was "wasted" as well. At any rate, I can only conclude you aren't finding my answers helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The region is currently not fully described, but it seems that it is the region below the curve $y=x^2+2$, above the $x$-axis, from $x=0$ to $x=4$.

We do it two ways, by slicing (disk, really washer since it has a hole)  and by shells.

**Slicing:** The vertical distance from the "top curve" $y=x^2+2$ to the line $y=-2$ is $(x^2+2)-(-2)$, that is, $x^2+4$. The distance from the bottom curve $y=0$ to the line $y=-2$ is $2$. It follows that the volume of the solid of revolution is 
$$\int_{x=0}^4 \pi\left((x^2+4)^2 -2^2\right)\,dx.$$
To integrate, expand the square. The calculation is routine.

**Shells:** Look at a thin horizontal strip of width "$dy$" at height $y$. The length of this strip is $x$, which is $\sqrt{y-2}$. The radius of the circle through which this strip rotates is the distance from the strip to $y=-2$, which is $y+2$.  "Add up," $y=2$ to $y=4^2+2=18$. Our volume is
$$\int_{y=2}^{18}2\pi(y+2)\sqrt{y-2}\,dy.$$

The mechanics of the integration are essentially the same as those described by amWhy.  Let $u=y-2$. Then $y+2=u+4$, and $du=dy$. So we want
$$\int_{u=0}^{16} \pi(u+4)\sqrt{u}\,du=\int_{u=0}^{16} 2\pi(u^{3/2}+4u^{1/2})\,du.$$`